# The points doesn'tupdated when a user completed an offer in AyeTStudios Offerwall

Tags: java, android, gradle, callback, sdk

recently i implemented the AyeT Offerwall to my android app, all worked fine but when an user complete an offer doesn't update the coins. It says you can manage users balance with a callback URL but i haven't website so i use the UserBalanceCallback Listener, i follow the docs step by step but not update the points.

Docs: https://www.ayetstudios.com/helpcenter/publisher-sdk-integration

All works fine, the error is only not update the coins. This is the code i have:

```java
 private void taskSdkInit() {

        String identifier = user.getUid();

        AyetSdk.init(getApplication(), identifier, new UserBalanceCallback() {
            @Override
            public void userBalanceChanged(SdkUserBalance sdkUserBalance) {

                int reward = sdkUserBalance.getAvailableBalance();

                updateData(reward);

            }
```

```java
private void updateData(int reward) {

        int currentCoins = Integer.parseInt(coinsTv.getText().toString());
        int updatedCoins = currentCoins + reward;

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("coins", updatedCoins);

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                .child(user.getUid())
                .updateChildren(map)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Coins updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });

    }
```

```java
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = auth.getCurrentUser();

        taskSdkInit();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

```java
if (AyetSdk.isInitialized()) {

                    AyetSdk.showOfferwall(getApplication(), "Adslot name");

                } else {
                    Log.e("error", "Failed to init sdk");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation looks good, adding a log below

```
int reward = sdkUserBalance.getAvailableBalance();
```

could tell you if you are not getting user balance from sdk or if its lost further down the line, you can consult ayetstudios sdk demo app at https://github.com/ayetstudios/ayet-android-sdk-demo-app for more complete example set.

Comment: Hi, when i log that return number 0